# Regex for matching every occurrence of text between two characters, only between specific characters

Tags: regex

Here's an example

I would like to regex match any text between quotes ''

I want this match:

```
foo('text1', 'text2', 'text3' ....)
```

I don't want to match:

```
bar('text1', 'text2', 'text3' ....)
```

I don't want to match

```
'text1'
```

So i wanted the match the text1 text2 text3 ..etc.. only when between foo(). Matching only the text between the quotes"" and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```
 \bfoo\(\K|\G(?!^)'([^')]*)'[^')]*
```

You can try this,Grab the matches.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/YG5D42/1

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly in the demo. But it's not working for my specific use case. Do regex expressions usually have a 'single' matching expression? My guess is because of multiple matches its getting somewhat confused. Idk though

Comment: @nicwhitts which language are you using ? Why isnt it working? Any errors

Comment: Im actually trying to set the config for tailwind intellisense: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense
But using the emacs lsp-mode:
`(lsp-register-custom-settings '(("tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex" ["['`]([^'`]*)['`]"])))`
Here's a demo of this expression that works: https://regex101.com/r/BE6cc8/1
But as you can see it will match any occurrence of '' quotes. Id like to restrict to just tw.style('') like in the demo. Im pretty new to lisp and emacs so im guessing there's something going wrong between the lsp-mode config and tailwind intellisense config.

Comment: not sure if \K or \G is supported or not